# How is IPChicken Remembering My IP?

Tags: ruby, networking, proxy, ip-address, socks

How does IP chicken remember my proxy IP address even though the proxy is turned off and the cookies cleared out? How do I make it to so the second time I visit ipchicken it shows the IP with no proxy?

```
require 'socksify'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
#port forwarding set up on port 9999
TCPSocket::socks_server = 'localhost'
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9999
p agent.get("http://www.ipchicken.com").text #IP SHOWS PROXY IP
p agent.cookie_jar.jar #SHOWS IPCHICKEN COOKIE
agent.cookie_jar.clear!
p agent.cookie_jar.jar #SHOWS NO COOKIES
TCPSocket::socks_server = nil
TCPSocket::socks_port = nil
p agent.get("http://www.ipchicken.com").text #SHOWS PROXY IP
p agent.get("http://www.whatismyipaddress.com").text #SHOWS IP WITH NO PROXY
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a command-line tool like `curl` or your browser? Does Mechanize cache?

Comment: I think this is a mechanize specific problem.  if i use nokogiri instead of mechanize than the problem goes away.  but what can mechanize cache? i deleted the cookie.  and even if i start a new agent instance it still returns the old IP address

Comment: Like a browser cache it might have saved the content of the page. Try cache-busting: `http://www.ipchicken.com/?t=1290313` where the number on the end is just random junk.

Comment: what is cache busting? and how do i cache bust if Mechanize documentation says it doesnt cache pages

Comment: We're talking diagnostics here. You keep trying things to rule out probable causes. That's how it works. These sites don't use cookies to figure out your IP, they use the header they're given from the server. Maybe Mechanize recycles the same TCPSocket settings for all connections after the first one. Try making a new `agent`.

Comment: if i turn socksify on, scrape, then turn it off and WAIT 5 seconds, scrape... the 2nd IP address read is different.  that 5 second wait time works.